# Kendo SchedulerDataSource not sending JSON but form style data instead

Tags: json, kendo-ui, datasource, scheduler

With Kendo 2018.2.516 SchedulerDataSource and using the code below:
Note: I have tried with and without contentType

```
update: {
          type: "POST",
          url: "https://localhost:44346/api/xxxx",
          dataType: "json",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        },
```

What is being sent to the WebAPI server is not json but form style data:

id=1&title=Test+123+789&description=Test+456&start=Sat+Jul+14+2018+01%3A00%3A00+GMT-0400+(Eastern+Daylight+Time)&end=Sat+Jul+14+2018+02%3A00%3A00+GMT-0400+(Eastern+Daylight+Time)

Any suggestions on how to make this json?

Thank you!

Alan Painter

Comment: I updated to Kendo 2018.2.620 -- still the same form style results .i.e. no json

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement is to send JSON to the controller, you will need to **stringify** your data models being sent.

The Kendo UI [transport.create](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/transport.create) documentation discusses the technique.

Two ways are:

- `parameterMap` returns `{ models: kendo.stringify(data.models) }`, or
- `transport.create` function is a `$ajax()` with
   `data: { models: kendo.stringify(options.data.models)}`